# Template Sort In C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, sorting

Hey all, I'm trying to write a sort function but am having trouble figuring out how to initialize a value, and making this function work as a generic template.  The sort works by:

> Find a pair =(ii,jj)= with a minimum  value = ii+jj = such at A[ii]>A[jj]
>       If such a pair exists, then
>         swap A[ii] and A[jj]    else
>          break;

The function I have written is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void sort(T *A, int size)
{
 T min =453;
 T temp=0;
 bool swapper = false;
  int index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
  for (int ii = 0; ii < size-1; ii++){
   for (int jj = ii + 1; jj < size; jj++){
    if((min >= (A[ii]+A[jj])) && (A[ii] > A[jj])){
     min = (A[ii]+A[jj]);
     index1 = ii;
     index2 = jj;    
     swapper = true;
    }
   }
  }
  if (!swapper)
   return;
  else
  {
   temp = A[index1];
   A[index1] = A[index2];
   A[index2] = temp;
   sort(A,size);
  }
 }
```

This function will successfully sort an array of integers, but not an array of chars. **I do not know how to properly initialize the min value for the start of the comparison.** I tried initializing the value by simply adding the first two elements of the array together (min = A[0] + A[1]), but it looks to me like for this algorithm it will fail. I know this is sort of a strange type of sort, but it is practice for a test, so thanks for any input.

Comment: What happens when you try to sort an array of chars?

Comment: It does not sort the array of characters.

Comment: std::sort not functional for you?

Comment: Could you describe what the `min` value is for? As far as I can see, it would work exactly the same without it (except wouldn't potentially break on overflows): detect an out-of-order pair (with O(n*n) compexity! - bubble-sort would have finished by now), repeat until no pairs are out of order. - Are you sure this isn't a broken implementation of Selection sort (with recursion as an extra requirement), where you'd just use the first value of the subrange as the current smallest?

Comment: @visitor Yes, the min value is something that is given in the problem statement, the algorithm can only switch the elements if the pair is out of order AND the sum of the two elements is the smallest available.  I understand that its not a practical algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely reason it fails, is because `char = 453`  does not produce 453 but rather different number, depending what char is (signed versus unsigned).  your immediate solution would be to use numerical_limits, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/

you may also need to think about design, because char has small range, you are likely to overflow often when adding two chars.

Comment: I know that I can't have char = 453, that is my problem.  I don't know what to set this initial min value to, but I know it must be larger than the largest sum possible in the array.

Comment: @wdow check the link, then u can use `numeric_limits<T>::max()` the greatest value of type, which you can use as your smallest value

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value of any type is `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`. It's defined in `<limits>`.

Also, consider a redesign. This is not a good algorithm. And I would make sure I knew what I was doing before calling my `sort` function recursively.

Comment: I understand that this is a very poorly designed algorithm.  I did not come up with the algorithm, it is just an example that I was told to implement.  I suppose it would be better to use a while loop instead of calling sort recursively, or do you have a more elegant idea?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't put too much time reading your algorithm, but as an alternative to `std::numeric_limits`, you can use the initial element in your array as the initial minimum value.  Then you don't have to worry about what happens if you call the function with a class that doesn't specialize `std::numeric_limits`, and thus can't report a maximum value.